# Help with digital switching for use with 555 timer

Tags: transistors, circuits

I have a 555 timer set up in astable configuration to output simple audible tones. But instead of having mechanical switches to choose the resistor that ultimately determines the output frequency, I would like to drive this circuit with a microcontroller and I would like a signal on a transistor for example, to control the path taken for the discharge/charging between the capacitor and resistors. I have attached an image of a similar schematic, however, mine is a little varied in that I put the switches in series with the corresponding resistor (so each switch only activates one resistor instead of a cumaltive total). Basically, instead of those switches choosing the resistor of R1 through R9, how can I implement a transistor to control this? To be specific I'm planning on using an ATMEGA 4809 for the signals that will correspond to each tone and choose the resistor, but a general answer for how I should approach the design is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Mentioned Circuit]

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, just use the MCU *instead of* the 555

Comment: You should look into timers on the Atmega (http://pcarduino.blogspot.com/2013/10/generating-tones-with-timers.html). They will allow you to generate tones much more accurately than the 555, with much more customisation, fewer components (basically just a single transistor), and the cpu wont have to spend any time on it (the timer runs independently)

Comment: it makes no sense to control that circuit with a microcontroller ... use the microcontroller to drive the speaker

Comment: You could have the MCU control the setting of a digital potentiometer.